# GWT OnScroll event does not fire

Tags: java, gwt, scroll

I have a small app that wraps a `TextArea` inside a `ScrollPanel`.

When I instantiate the `ScrollPanel` and attach a `ScrollEventHandler` WITHIN `OnModuleLoad()` - the `OnScroll` event fires properly.

However, when I create a separate `Composite` class for the `ScrollPanel` wrapping a `TextArea`, attach the handler to it - the `OnScroll` does NOT fire. I can see the composite widget on screen and no compile or runtime errors are displayed but still - nothing happens when I scroll.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added `sinkEvents(Event.ONSCROLL)`?

The `Composite` widget is a somewhat strange compilation that claims the inner Widget as itself.
Try to create your own 'Widget' and use the `setElement(DOM.createDiv())` and your own widget. This may help if the `sinkEvent(int)` code not working.